# Data Agent - SELECT from one table and insert into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is there any type of product where I can write a SQL statement to select from one table and then insert into another database (The other database is out in the cloud).  Also, it needs to be able to check to see if that record exists and then update the row if anything has changed.    Then it will need to run every 10-30 minutes to check to see what has changed or if new records have been added.

The source database and the ending database have a different schema (if that matters?)  I've been looking, but it seams that only products out there are ones that will just copy one table and insert into a table with the same schema.

Comment: That is pretty much the way it works.  You'd have to manually modify the data along the way to match the target.

Comment: Sure but as you noted you will need to write the sql for this kind of thing. Shouldn't be a big deal to write the sql. Then just create a sql job and schedule however frequently you want/need.

Comment: sql job?  Guess I have never heard of that.  I will look into it.  I guess the part I'm having trouble getting my head around is how do I check to see if the record exist and know to update that row instead of inserting a new row?

Comment: There are already questions with answers about how to "update if exists, else insert in SQL"

Comment: I did not know any of these things existed.  Now I know where to look.  Thanks.